# What to do with the [address] tag?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

The tag excerpt and wiki for [address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) are empty but there are <strike>9 questions</strike> 6 questions related to regular (physical?) addresses and to email addresses. In the context of Web Applications it looks to be a meta-tag as it has at least two different meanings and it doesn't make sense to use it alone.

Should it be burninated or it should be specialized to be used for email addresses or to regular addresses?

**Additional details**

Questions by combination of tags

- [address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) and [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)......................... : <strike>[5 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address+email)</strike>
- [address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) and [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) but not [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)... : <strike>[1 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address+gmail+-email)</strike>
- [address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) and [google-maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)................ : <s>[3 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address+google-maps)</s>
- [address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) and closed........................ : <strike>[3 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baddress%5D+closed%3A1)</strike>

Comment: I just removed [tag:address] without doing any other change to closed questions as they were duplicates of other questions.

Comment: Possible related tags for questions tagged with [address and google-maps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address+google-maps): 1) [tag:geolocation] (44 questions) 2) [tag:contact-address] (6 questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there isn't any question with [address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address), so it looks that there isn't to do with it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Any benefit of this tag seems marginal. And there are drawbacks: ambiguous name is one. Another drawback is that inexperienced users typing "email address" in the tag field will tag with both.

I support removing this tag from all questions.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with [Sally](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3971/354). For the questions with both `email` and `address`, it looks like it was meant to be [email-address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-address), but that tag doesn't do much to better categorize the questions. At least one of those is really about a Google Account, and so should be tagged with [google-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-account). The others don't seem to need `address` at all.

*All* of the questions look like they need some extra work, so don't *just* remove the tag. A couple look like they simply don't have the right tags at all.